# How to find for aws log groups the corresponding ressource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

due to huge costs in our environment, I have a task to create a lambda to tag all log groups like corresponding resources (the source of these log groups). However, I am facing a challenge to identify the resource arn of log groups. There are many logs in our environment like logs for lambda, logs for elastic-beanstalk, logs for ec2. But how can I match the log group with the corresponding resource? I would appreciate any help very much!

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to get the arn of the resource who stream to log group?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using [describe-log-groups](https://www.google.com/search?q=aws+cli+describe-log-groups&oq=aws+cli+describe-log&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.7161j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). To use it you'll need to work your way "backwards" by going from resources to the log-groups, but I can't think of any other way at the moment.

```
aws logs describe-log-groups --query 'logGroups[*].arn' --log-group-name-prefix '/aws/lambda/[name-of-your-lambda]'
```

Output:

> [
>      "arn:aws:logs:[region]:[account-id]:log-group:/aws/lambda/[name-of-your-lambda]:*"
>   ]

Hope that helps.